# Instagram api sandbox allowed or not

Tags: instagram-api

Which endpoints are allowed in just sandbox before approval process? I read about the "extended" permissions you can request after approval..but seem's like follower list and users/search?q= is not working.

So how am I supposed to show them a screencast/video of my app working required for the approval? I have 2 sandbox users I'm testing with..

Answer (score 0):

You can use all endpoints in sandbox mode, the only difference is is that only sandbox users you have defined and their posts exist. Everyone else and their media is invisible to your client.

For example: MyUserA is a Sandbox user (defined in your client settings) MyUserB is not. Search for "MyUser" will show MyUserA but not MyUserB

For search you must also have added `scope=public_content` to your authorisation request. This will work in sandbox, but not production unless you have applied for and been accepted for the scope

Comment: Ok and since I fall under the Instagram use case of; "1) To help individuals share their own content with 3rd party apps" -is it true that ONLY "basic" permission will be given? even though I need follower_list + public_content.  Under valid use cases here: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/ it seems like basic will only be given...

Comment: If you can demonstrate a valid use for needing a scope I don't think the use cases they give are seton stone. Before you go any further bare in mind that they removed the endpoint to see OTHER peoples follower list. You can only see your own followers, or rather the followers of the access token owner. userA can't authorise your app and see userB's followers

Comment: Ok that's good enough for me, only need to see the followers of the access token owner. -This is still follower_list though, right? Appreciate the clear and fast responses you've given!

Comment: In Sandbox.. only the Admin (main instagram user/that invites the others) the permissions seems to work. I can search public_content and find my sandbox users but sandbox user can't search and find the main admin user... Is this right??